# redirect I/Os in GDB in MI mode

Tags: gdb

with normal interpreter, one can run a program with redirected inputs and outputs like this:

```
run < input_file > output_file
```

In MI mode, run command equivalent is -exec-run but it does not take argument for I/O redirection and I did not find any dedicated command.

What is the way to do redirection in MI mode ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-exec-arguments` for this:

```
-exec-arguments < /path/to/somefile
-exec-run
```

Comment: There should be -exec-arguments > /path/to/somefile